# Angularjs deleting the item from array and mongoDb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

A delete button click calls this

```
    $scope.remove=function(item){ 
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item),1);
};
```

If delete button is clicked, the item does disappear but after refreshing it is back in the list. How do I permanently delete it form database as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is create a method on the server side which deletes a document
from the database using the input parameter id.

Send a HTTP request to your server that contains the above method and item id as parameters.

Check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) page for AngularJS $http documentation.

Deleting a document from the database is done using the MongoDB [remove](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) operation.

The exact syntax for the remove operation depends on the programming language
that you are using on the server side.

Check [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) for documentation and examples on drivers available for MongoDB.